# Authenticating & Accessing APEX App page with URL

Tags: authentication, url, apex

I have an APEX application, with custom authentication scheme. It has multiple pages. After one user logs in to the application, he fills his questionnaire and wants to send the URL to evaluator, with some technical id.

URL looks something like this:

```
https://www.aaaaa.com/ords/f?p=APPID:PAGEID:SESSION::NO:RP,27:EVAL_ID:126676
```

Any one having this URL should be able to access this page, **without redirecting to login page**. Evaluator should be able to access this same page (questionnaire) through that URL and save his comments / corrections. Content to be loaded on this page will be decided by the attribute EVAL_ID. When loading this page, I will check if this is EVAL_ID is valid or not from my database. If valid, show the page / questions based on the EVAL_ID. All questions in DB will have an evaluator assigned to it. Most important thing is that evaluator should not be redirected to login page. He should see the questionnaire directly and login user name cookie should be set as the evaluator.

In other terms, I need to access the same page with custom auth scheme (user id / password) and with EVAL_ID. Any suggestions or guidance is highly appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by myself after a bit of effort. Posting it here might help someone.

1. Create new a "public" page in application. In this page, do the following.
2. Create a "Before Header" "Branch", with "Page or URL (Redirect)" to LOGIN page, with server side condition as "No Rows Returned" and SQL Query to validate the EVAL_ID received against my DB. If its not valid, no row will be returned and redirected to login page.
3. Create a "Before Header" "Process" as "PL/SQL Code", with following code to set the user cookie in case EVAL_ID is valid. Then redirect to questionnaire page. You can also set some application items here, if required.

   DECLARE
       v_username varchar2(200);
       v_password varchar2(50);
       v_goto_page int;

   BEGIN

   ```
   SELECT USER_EMAIL, PASSWORD
     INTO v_username, v_password
     FROM USERS_TABLE
    WHERE EVAL_ID = :eval_id;

   :GOTO_PAGE := v_goto_page;
   :APP_ITEM1 := 'aaaa';
   :APP_ITEM2 := 'bbbb';

   apex_authentication.send_login_username_cookie ( p_username => v_username, p_consent  => :P9999_REMEMBER = 'Y' );
   wwv_flow_custom_auth_std.login ( P_UNAME => v_username,
                                    P_PASSWORD => v_password,
                                    P_SESSION_ID => v('APP_SESSION'),
                                    P_FLOW_PAGE => :APP_ID || ':' || v_goto_page );
   ```

   END;